# Gaps in Windows graphs in Cacti

Tags: windows, monitoring, snmp, cacti

Why would I'd be getting gaps like this in graphs coming from Windows hosts?

[image: Graph showing gaps]

This problem seems to happen quite regularly on graphs coming from Windows hosts. The graph template for the graph above is "Host MIB - Available Disk Space", though this problem happens on all sorts of Windows graph templates.

Comment: Have you considered just firing up wirehark and filtering for snmp traffic destined for that host?  What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cacti gets no response from a query, it does not try again; the data for that time period is missing.

Check your cacti logs for clues or errors.

Comment: So this is likely caused by Windows SNMP agent not responding correctly? Can Cacti be made to try again?

Comment: SNMP retries are supported since 0.8.6i; in Console/Settings/General you can set the timeout and retry options.

Comment: Oh retries is already set to 3. That's upsetting! I've increased the timeout from 0.5s to 1s, though that seems a little extreme for SNMP.

Comment: If retrieving this data takes more than the timeout every time, it will never get data... consider setting the timeout to 5 seconds ? As long as all your data queries *combined* don't exceed 5 minutes, it doesn't matter. Also increase the number of parallel queries to 10 or more, to make the best use of the time you have.

Comment: Ah ok, so that timeout is the window for all queries going to that host, not just individual queries? SHOULD a windows host take this long to respond though? This happens with most of the windows hosts we monitor.

Comment: Where did I say any of that ?

Comment: you didn't? they're questions not statements...

Comment: Increasing the timeout period on all hosts worked. Thanks.